# Serializing Thread Execution Context in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Can the Thread Execution Context in C# be Serialized in one process and then the same could be De-Serialized in a different process ?

What are the dependencies that need to be justified ? Also, I am not able to get good resources to Thread Execution Context. Are you aware of any ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Comment: I am working on creating a SSO Service and I am evaluating approaches. Approach A: I get a token and impersonate or do identity delegation to achieve the goal. Approach B: If the execution context could be deserialized then, execute the code in the De-Serialized Execution Context. That's the thought. I am not sure, If I am thinking correctly.

Comment: It looks *plausible*, but I wonder if this is *sensible*... what are you actually trying to ***do***? that is usually a better place to start

Comment: Do you mean CPU registers too or did I misunderstand?  I would have thought it would have been encapsulated by the .NET Runtime

Comment: @MarcGravell - are you saying user can override thread execution context at will? do you have an example code i can try?

Comment: Have you find solution for serialization thread? I'm also interested in it. (look at c# virtual machine, that can serialize process https://github.com/cv-lang/virtual-machine